# Secure Google OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant on mobile

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I now researched quite some time to understand OAuth 1.0a, OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect. I read their RFCs/Specs and still have one question regarding Google and their Authorization Code Grant on mobile.

OAuth 2.0 states in chapter 4.1.3:

> The authorization server MUST require client authentication for confidential clients [...]

**My Question:**
How can Google ensure it's client authentication for a mobile client?

Thanks,
Dominik